# How to install/fix gdb on Big Sur macport after OS upgrade

Tags: macos, xcode, big-sur, macports, gcc

Given the following problem when trying to install gdb, which demands gcc6, which ridiculously requires gcc7, which refuses to compile under Xcode:

```
Error: To install this port upgrade Xcode to 11.3 or newer
Error: Failed to fetch libgcc7: incompatible Xcode version
```

I found several other links to not provide a viable solution.

Answer (score 2):

The solution that ultimately worked for me was:

1. Install the newest security patch for Big Sur - on Nov 22, 2021 a new one was released that claims to fix this exact issue, which it does not... on it's own
2. Install the newest Xcode (tested with Xcode 13.1)
3. `sudo rm -r /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` (yes really, installing a new one with the old present seems to break)
4. Find your proper Xcode Command Line Tools link here and install it: https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=command%20line%20tools
5. `sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`
6. `sudo port selfupdate`
7. `sudo port upgrade outdated`
8. `sudo port uninstall gcc6`
9. `sudo port install gcc8` (because gcc6 and gcc7 still don't install, and I suspect 9 and 10 will not either, as per https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=92061)
10. `sudo port install gdb`
11. `ggdb`

Yes, after all that, it installs it under a name not mentioned ever during installation. For [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19931857/gdb-command-not-found-when-installed-from-macports-mavericks).